# Will you publish Winter Bash 2015 source code for snowball animation?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015

I like the snowball animation for Winter Bash 2015 - do you plan to make the source code public? It would be a great inspiration for making similar animations for our own projects!

Comment: Are you referring _specifically_ to the snowfall animation or the entire codebase for the Winter Bash website and the JavaScript injected into SE sites?

Comment: I am referring to the snowball fight source code. I suppose it's scripted in JavaScript - I would like to explore the source code of these little guys fighting each other and find out how I could create something similar.

Comment: Well, being client side it is public and accessible by anyone, but they obfuscate the variable and methods names, making it really hard to figure what's going on.

Comment: It's all with the client, so if you are up for a week of unminifying, it's all yours... ;)

Comment: The question is not "will you make it public", but "will you make it public *and license it in such a way that I can use it*". Because you wouldn't use unlicensed code, would you?